# Confusion over a JTable's setDefaultRenderer method

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I've currently got an SSCCE (or at least a medium one) that has a table, a model that extends AbstractTableModel, and a cell renderer that extends the DefaultTableCellRenderer.

I'm trying to convert a column, containing a `LocalDate` (a birthdate), into an age. So I tried making a "test" custom renderer to see if I could get a renderer working:

```
class CustomDateCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{
    @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable tab, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                                                        boolean hasFocus, int r, int c){
        if(value instanceof LocalDate){
            System.out.println("Local Date");
            // this is where I display the age from the value variable
        }
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(tab,value,isSelected,hasFocus,r,c);
    }
}
```

it worked, if I called:

`table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(new CustomDateCellRenderer());`

but not if I used:

`table.setDefaultRenderer(LocalDate.class, new CustomDateCellRenderer());`

I'm trying to understand why, especially as the value argument to getTableCellRendererComponent() is definitely a LocalDate. I'm guessing it might be that the column already has a default cell renderer at the time I'm trying to set one. As described in the JTable/method's documentation:

> Sets a default cell renderer to be used **if no renderer has been set in a TableColumn**

Does that sound like the problem? I'm just confused because I've certainly not set one myself.

I'm happy to provide the entire SSCCE if needed, but for the moment, and to keep things shorter, here's my TableModel's getValueAt() and setValueAt() methods:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int r, int c){
    Person p = data.get(r);
    switch(c){
        case 0 :    p.setFName((String)value); break;
        case 1 :    p.setSName((String)value); break;
        case 2 :    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    p.setDOB(LocalDate.parse((String)value, formatter)); break;
    }
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int r, int c){
    Person p = data.get(r);
    switch(c){
        case 0 : return p.getFName(); 
        case 1 : return p.getSName(); 
        case 2 : return p.getDOB(); 
    }
    return null;
}
```

data is just an arraylist of type Person (a class which has the obvious variables (String)fName, (String)sName and (LocalDate)DOB)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I found out that I'd not overridden the getColumnClass() method in the TableModel. Amateur mistake by an amateur!

this meant that `table.setDefaultRenderer(LocalDate.class, new CustomDateCellRenderer());` wouldn't work, but getting the column and setting the renderer would.

I'm not sure if was the best approach, but this is my getColumnClass method now:

```
@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int c){
    switch(c){
        case 0 : return String.class;
        case 1 : return String.class;
        case 2 : return LocalDate.class;
    }
    return null;
}
```